# How to add except clause to Spark SQL similar to what databricks provides

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I'm looking for a way to incorporate the `select * except(col1, ...)` clause provided by Databricks into my workflow. Although I don't utilize Databricks, I would like to introduce this `select except` clause either as a spark-package or by modifying the Spark project itself. However, I'm unsure about how to begin this process and would appreciate guidance from the community. Thank you for your assistance.

ref: https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html#examples

Comment: Could you please tell which API are you using and if the [Dataset.drop()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org%2Fapache%2Fspark%2Fsql%2FDataset.html=) method or the [regex_column_names](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html) part of a SELECT statement would work for you?

Comment: "except" is already part of SQL and Spark `select_statement [ { UNION | INTERSECT | EXCEPT } [ ALL | DISTINCT ] `  [ref.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select.html) But, NOT in the manner you are seeking - traditional advice is to reference only the columns you require which I would still adhere to in databricks.

Comment: @LeonidVasilev the regex column name matching would not work for my use case as there's no clear pattern to the column names.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell I understand that EXCEPT is already present in spark as a set different operation, but I would still like to explore the option of adding a syntax similar to what databricks is offering.